# NullPointerException at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznu.onCreate

Tags: android

Sometime a received report from my user about this crash issue.

I cannot reproduce it with my device. It happen at the first time launch app and this is the stack trace from crash reporter:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.my.app.package.name/com.my.app.package.name.activity.Dispatcher}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.my.app.package.name/com.my.app.package.name.activity.Dispatcher}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2127)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.my.app.package.name/com.my.app.package.name.activity.Dispatcher}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3179)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2600)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2127)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznu.onCreate(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpc.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:175)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5347)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2600)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2127)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Any one can help me with this?

Comment: Well apparently your Exception is in `onCreate` I suppose. share the activity code please.

Comment: Yes, i got that too when use GoogleSignInApi. I have the report from Crashlytics

Comment: I open an issue here https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/240

Comment: Getting same crash in google sign in...any help ?